# What is plagiarism in this answer?

Tags: discussion, moderation, plagiarism

This [answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/13185/279) from a new users was deleted for plagiarism. I did a quick search of the answer and did not find any copy and past text. Even I could not even find quoted verse in the page. Not sure what is plagirms here. I am concerned that new users are  no welcomed here. Instead of a friendly message, their answers are deleted right away. Obviously he has provided an answer and did some research. Can I better understand what is plagiarism here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you didn't search properly.

[Here](http://islam.com/questions/27466/is-love-allowed)'s the original source. It certainly is plagiarism.

Comment: Interestingly the link in the answer did not contain copy and past text. We probably still not to be a little more welcoming to new users though.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256051/1309352